# replacing "span" tag with "input" tag results in displaying of extra "<" and ">" in php while using preg_replace

Tags: php, html

I am trying to replace a string having span tag with the input tag as follows

original string:

```
<span style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 12pt;"><img width="56" height="25" src="image023.gif" style="vertical-align:middle"></span>
```

the string i want to change:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="choice"><img width="56" height="25" src="image023.gif" style="vertical-align:middle"></input>
```

mycode is:

```
$oldstr1='<span style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 12pt;">';
$oldstr2='</span>';
$newstr1='<input type="radio" value="1" name="choice">';
$newstr2="</input>";
$str=A super set html content of the span i mentioned;

while (preg_match($oldstr1, $str) && preg_match($oldstr2, $str)) {

    $str = preg_replace($oldstr1,$newstr1, $str, 1);
    $str = preg_replace($oldstr2,$newstr2, $str, 1);

}

return $str;
```

However, the output i am getting is having extra "<" and ">" tags in the output. like "<" and then the radio button with proper tags and again an extra ">" at the end.Please suggest.

Comment: what does `$str` have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't set your delimiters, and your strings are not properly escaped. It works if you do that, e.g.

```
$oldstr1='/\<span style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 12pt;"\>/';
$oldstr2='/\<\/span\>/';
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your patterns. `$oldstr1` and `$oldstr2`.

@Flosi posted correct answer, but here alternative solution - in your case you can use `str_replace` which will be faster (without while loop and you dont need to change your patterns):

```
$str = str_replace($oldstr1,$newstr1, $str);
$str = str_replace($oldstr2,$newstr2, $str);
```

Comment: I am using str_replace but the output wont have </input> end tag which iam in needof.Any suggestions?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/28ec34c0de8e8d1517691bb8541a22599352b714 here is working example

Answer (score 1):

Try to add '/' to your old string. Like this:

```
$oldstr1='/<span style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 12pt;">/';
$oldstr2='/<\/span>/';
```

**EDIT:** I guess for your case, would be better to use @MarkS answer and just replace instead of regex.

Comment: yes, you are correct iam going to use str_ireplace instead of preg_replace.